# dart enforce subtype in generic type (disallow base type) VS switch(Foo<T>)

Tags: dart, dart-analyzer

Given such classes

```
sealed class Base { /* ... */ }

class X extends Base { /* ... */ }
class Y extends Base { /* ... */ }

class Foo<T extends Base> {
   final T t;
   const Foo({required this.t});
}
```

Reading the [docs](https://dart.dev/language/generics#restricting-the-parameterized-type) it seems impossible to restrict the type of an instance of `Foo<T>` so that `T` must be a real sub types of `Base` and may not be `Base`. Is it possible?

Background is that I want to switch over a `Foo<T>` instance:

```
final a = Foo<X>(/* ... */);

final result = switch (a) {
  Foo<X> _ => 'x',
  Foo<Y> _ => 'y',
  Foo<Base> _ => throw 'does not exist'; // <--
}
```

The [`missing_enum_constant_in_switch` rule](https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#missing_enum_constant_in_switch) requires me to specify the `Base _` case. That is bad, because it matches all cases, so that if we later add a new `class Z extends Base {/* ... */}`, the rule would no longer report a missing case but just use the `Foo<Base>` case and throw `does not exist`.

Given that `Base` is `sealed` it also is `abstract` and hence cannot be instantiated and hence I would expect the compiler to not require that case - but I understand that it does, because in general the type restriction allows for `Foo<Base>`.

As a workaround I am currently switching over `a.t`.

```
final a = Foo<X>(/* ... */);

final result = switch (a.t) {
  X _ => 'x',
  Y _ => 'y',
  // no `Base` case is required.
}
```

This looks fine in an example, but is very cumbersome and error prone in realistic production code, because it would require a manual **unchecked** cast of `a` if downstream functions depend on `a` rather than on `a.t`:

```
final a = Foo<X>(/* ... */);

final result = switch (a.t) {
  // THIS IS NOT POSSIBLE
  X _ => somethingX(a as Foo<X>),
  Y _ => somethingY(a as Foo<Y>),
}
```

This would not work, because `a` is of type `Foo<Base>` and hence flutter throws `type 'Foo<Base>' is not a subtype of type 'Foo<X>' in type cast`.

Hence, we further must workaround by changing `somethingX` and `somethingY` to also accept the downcasted value like this:

```
final a = Foo<X>(/* ... */);
final t = a.t;
final result = switch (t) {
  X _ => somethingX(a, t),
  Y _ => somethingY(a, t),
}
```

or by doing something like:

```
final a = Foo<X>(/* ... */);
final t = a.t;
final result = switch (t) {
  X _ => somethingX(a.cast<X>()),
  Y _ => somethingY(a.cast<Y>()),
}
```

where `cast` is:

```
Foo<T extends Base> {
  // ...

  Foo<T2> cast<T2 extends Base>() => Foo(
    t: t as T2,
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible.

Dart type parameters are *only* restricted by subtype checks, so there is no way to accept both `X` and `Y` and also not accept `Base`, not with the current definitions.

The one hack you'd probably try, and which won't actually work, is to have a hidden shared superclass:

```dart
class Base {}
class _SecretBase extends Base {}
class X extends _SecretBase {}
class Y extends _SecretBase {}

class Foo<T extends _SecereteBase> { ... }
```

Then you'd think that someone outside of your library would not be able to create a `Foo<_SecretBase>`, and they can't use `Base`, so would have to use one of the proper subtypes of `Base`.
Sadly it doesn't work, since a raw type like `new Foo()` would "instantiate to bounds" and create a `Foo<_SecretBase>`, even if the caller couldn't write the type.

So, it's not possible to restrict type arguments to proper subtypes of a shared supertype.

Comment: nice idea with the secret class though